# Problem with installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: windows, dual-boot, installation

I have my notebook with the preinstalled Windows 7. I've decided to try Ubuntu as well. Unfortunately I couldn't manage to install it. I was following the guide "[How to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/22/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-04/).

After booting Ubuntu from the liveUSB and proceeding to the "Allocate drive space" dialogue box, I've discovered that the installed Windows 7 couldn't be identified and there is no item "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7".

In this situation I've chosen "Something else" item for manual partition allocation. But at the next dialogue box I couldn't find any of my 4 partitions. The only item which is visible is "/dev/sda/".

My question, what was wrong? And what should I do to overcome the stated issue?

P.S.: Initially there are was a problem with installation of Ubuntu due to the dynamic disk type. Using the EASEUS Partition Master I've revert it to basic disk type.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see on your report it looks like you used WUBI to install your version of Ubuntu, but from the USB. There is a MBR Bootloader error on Sda7. This is where Ubuntu resides and Wubi is present. Because of this error your unable to boot into Windows.

WUBI stands for Windows Based Ubuntu Installer which is used to install Ubuntu literally within the Windows NTFS file system. In fact there is no partitioning involved as the Ubuntu OS resides within the Windows NTFS directory as a folder.

Somewhere along the lines WUBI didn't finish completing the Grub entry or something

You'll need to repair Windows first by popping in your Windows CD...then going to the Repair Windows selection. Then afterwards perform a chkdsk. This should correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try tot do this: boot repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I've tried boot-repair, thanks @Julien for reply, and received the following report after executing it: [boot-repair report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/793168/). In report there is an overlapping partitions error. So I just wonder weather it is the reason for the initial problem?

Comment: So far i can see your Ubuntu is not installed on ext4 but on nfts partition? This is not correct.  Try to download Gparted, burn it on a disc and boot with this disc.  You will see the different partitions.  I suppose you must recreate the Ubuntu partition (ext4), and reinstall Ubuntu on that partition.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Wubi Method Of Installation for installing Ubuntu alongside Windows. It is just an easy method. In this method:

1. Open the downloaded ISO file.
2. Run Wubi.exe.
3. Select the relevant options on the Ubuntu Installer Window that open.
4. Select "Reboot Now" and Click Finish.

For more details visit this [link](http://www.99computertips.com/2015/03/install-ubuntu-directly-from-windows-on.html).